# deploying Opigno on azure website

Tags: php, azure, drupal-7, azure-web-app-service

I have created Azure website ,and upload all OPIGNO files to that website via FTP,so when i am trying to access the `index.php` for OPIGNO project ,it returns **server error 500**????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when there are anything went wrong, the server will return error 500. And usually a framework application occur 500 error after deploying on Azure Web Apps, maybe there are something configuration errors.

Also, you may need to turn the `display_errors` setting on to display errors for troubleshooting. You can follow the below steps to change the configuration:

1, Add a .user.ini file to your root directory.

2,add `display_errors=On` in this file

3, display_errors=On

4, Restart the web app.

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations for more information.

Answer (score 0):

## **General Setup for Opigno 3x**

1. *Added the following lines in the php.ini*

---

```
memory_limit 256M
upload_max_filesize 100M
post_max_size 200M
max_execution_time 3600
max_input_time 1000
```

---

2. *In the php.ini of the server (XAMPP). The php version must be
   7.4.Activate zend_extension for better performance (opcache).*

---

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
;Determines if Zend OPCache in enabled
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

---

3. In my.ini XAMPP MySQL configuration.

---

```
max_allowed_packet=100M.
```

---

4. https://www.opigno.org/download is where I downloaded the .tar file (opigno_with_dependencies-v3.0.2) and https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_lms is what I followed for the installation.